# UPDATE query with PHP + MySQLi works but always set 0 on quantity field

Tags: php, mysqli, prestashop

I'm desperated with this update query.

I need to update the quantity of a lot of products in Prestashop and I'm using a little PHP script and XML with quantities and IDs to make this.

```
<?php

    $ruta="XML/".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];   
    $prueba = simplexml_load_file($ruta);
    foreach ($prueba as $libro):

//From XML
    $id=$libro->vendorListingid; //From XML
    $quantity=$libro->quantity['amount'];

//The XML have 6 digits with 0
    $id=ltrim($id, "0");  

// Relationship between the XML and the database
    $consulta3 = "SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE reference='$id';"; 
    $rows=mysqli_query($con_presta,$consulta3);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rows)){ 
        echo $idfinal=$row[0]; 
    }

//THE QUERY
     echo $consulta = "UPDATE ps_product SET quantity=$quantity WHERE id_product=$idfinal;";



// LAUNCH!
    if ($con_presta->query($consulta) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $con_presta->error;
    }

   endforeach;
?>
```

The result is OK and the echo $consulta is ="UPDATE ps_product SET ps_product.quantity='2' WHERE ps_product.id_product='1';" for the first product (is an example), but the script set 0 and the query is OK because it works fine in PHPMyAdmin

[image: Table Definition]

Comment: try `UPDATE ps_product SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE id_product='$idfinal';`

Comment: I have put single quotes around `$quantity` variable

Comment: Can you put the table definition in the post as well please?

Comment: I put the table definition in the post. With the single quotes around variables not work. I have the same problem.

Comment: "but the script set 0 and the query is OK because it works fine in PHPMyAdmin", exactly where is it set to "0"?

Comment: @Rolige Column quantity default value is 0. @pekk3n Don't know exactly why it's not updating, but you're trying to update wrong table anyway. You should have a look into `ps_stock_available` table, that's where the real quantities are stored.

Comment: On the XML the first product have quantity=2, and the echo is "UPDATE ps_product SET quantity='2' WHERE id_product='1';. If I put this query on PHPMyAdmin works fine, but when I run the script, the echo is OK and $con_presta->query($consulta) is OK (no errors), but when I go to check the quantity to PHPMyAdmin is set 0

Comment: @TheDrot I trying to update ps_product and ps_stock_available. I have the same problem with the other table but I show only one case to simplify the problem

Comment: As @TheDrot said, the quantity of the product is not managed from the `ps_product` table, if you want a recommendation, you are using a script, why don't try to include the `/config/config.inc.php` and use the classes from PS, there is one to increase / decrease the stock.

Comment: Can't reproduce this, did you check data in XML? Maybe there's some weird data in there, could be duplicated references setting your stocks to 0.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
$stock = StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct((int) $idfinal, 0, 1);
if ($stock != $quantity) {
     StockAvailable::setQuantity((int) $idfinal, 0, (int) $quantity, 1);
}
```

Regards